# Python: Using glib.timeout_add to run asynchronous functions with out locking UI

Tags: python, gtk

I'm writing a UI that requires an user to be logged in. The login by itself can take up to 10 seconds. After the login, a lengthy call to a function that downloads and populates a TreeView is made. I've attempted to use `glib.timeout_add()` as to not lock the UI while the login and `populatelist()` functions are called but the gtk.main() still locks it.

```
def connect(self, widget, data):
    self.debug("Logging in")
    glib.timeout_add(500, self.login)
    self.debug("Logged in")

def login(self):
    self.debug("Starting self.gm.doLogin")
    logged_in = self.gm.doLogin(self.email, self.password)
    self.debug("Finsished self.gm.doLogin")
    if self.gm.logged_in:
        if self.connect_button.get_label() == "Connecting":
            self.debug("Getting SongWin")
            glib.timeout_add(500, self.populateSongWin)
            self.debug("Getting playLists")
            glib.timeout_add(500, self.populatePlaylists)
            self.action = "Getting songs"
            self.status_label.set_label("Status: %s; Songs: %s; Playlists: %s" %\
                                        (self.gm.logged_in, 
                                         len(self.gm.library),
                                         len(self.gm.playlists)))
            self.connect_button.set_label("Disconnect")
            self.connect_button.set_sensitive(True)
    self.action = "None"
    return False
```

I know this is working in some fashion because I can see:

```
DEBUG: Logging in
DEBUG: Logged in
DEBUG: Starting self.gm.doLogin
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Essentially the application needs to run in this order:

1. self.gm.doLogin()
2. self.populateSongWin()
3. self.populatePlaylists()

All three are time consuming, need to run sequentially, and not block the UI.

Comment: run login/lengthy call in a background thread, [example](http://askubuntu.com/a/183315/3712)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the application is blocked, but it is processing events.  One of the events has to terminate the loop.  You can check the idea behind the [event loops in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).

Nevertheless, in your code, you are using a local variable to get the login status, but you are using an instance variable to verify the status.

```
def login(self):
    self.debug("Starting self.gm.doLogin")
    logged_in = self.gm.doLogin(self.email, self.password)
    self.debug("Finsished self.gm.doLogin")
    if self.gm.logged_in:                                   <=
        [...]
```

Instead of `self.gm.logged_in` you should use `logged_in` in the condition for the `if` statement.